# Initialization of a back_inserter

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following code ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/9sa3MPjYr)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
    
    // auto b1 = std::back_inserter{v1};
    auto b2 = std::back_inserter(v1);
}
```

If I uncomment the line with `b1`, gcc gives the following error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:6:24: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from 'std::back_inserter'
    6 |         auto b1 = std::back_inserter{v1};
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:24: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto'
<source>:6:37: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
    6 |         auto b1 = std::back_inserter{v1};
      |
```

Using line with `b2`, on the other hand, compiles fine.

Why does the line with `b1` result in an error, while the line with `b2` compiles fine? If possible, can you point me to the relevant documentation in https://en.cppreference.com or in the standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::back_inserter` is a *function* that returns a `std::back_insert_iterator<Container>` instance:

```cpp
template< class Container >
constexpr std::back_insert_iterator<Container> back_inserter( Container& c );
```

You can't call functions using `{`...`}` as you try doing in `auto b1 = std::back_inserter{v1};`. To call a function, `(`...`)` needs to surround the arguments, as you do it in `auto b2 = std::back_inserter(v1);`.

Comment: Shame on me, I have no idea how I missed that looking at the docs! Thanks!

Comment: @rainer Easy miss :) You're welcome!